# PHP Setting Normal Variables Changing Session Variables

Tags: php, session, variables

I just suddenly starting having the weirdest problem I've ever seen, and nothing has changed except the host of my site. I use a lot of $_SESSION variables in my code that might have the same name as a normal variable, but setting the normal variable seems to be changing the $_SESSION variable with the same name.

For example, if I do

```
$_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'blue';
$favcolor = 'green';
echo $_SESSION['favcolor'];
```

I get `green` as the response... How do I not let this happen? I figure there's most likely some PHP ini variable that must be changed but I can't seem to find anything on this...

---

**SOLUTION**

So since I'm on an different host to host my site, I had to go by this in the following way. I created a `php.ini` file and put it in the root of my site's files with just the following line in it:

```
register_globals = Off ;notice the capital 'O' in 'Off'
```

Then in my .htaccess file I added this to the end of the file:

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/myhostusername/public_html/stumpyinc.com
<Files php.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
</IfModule>
```

No more conflicting variables! I also learned something from this experience and doing a little further research; variables and session variables shouldn't ever be the same anyways. It's a good practice that I will start to use throughout the rest of my programming.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is turned on. That will cause conflicts like you're experiencing. Your host probably forgot to turn them off when configuring the server. Once they do, your issue should go away.

If they refuse to turn it off, find a new host. Not only should `register_globals` be turned off, but they've been deprecated and will be removed in the next version of PHP.

Comment: You can also try turning it off if they refuse by using `ini_set("register_globals",0);`

Comment: @BrendanScarvell [Please note that `register_globals` **cannot** be set at runtime (`ini_set()`). Although, you can use _.htaccess_ if your host allows it as described above. An example _.htaccess_ entry: **php_flag register_globals off**.](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals)

Comment: Damn... It's really messing up my code since all of my sites have session variables that are the same as normal variables. I've tried adding the flags in my .htaccess but my new host doesn't allow me to add lines like that; they just throw a 500 error when any page is loaded

Comment: I added an exact solution to my problem in my answer, thanks for getting me there!